Are there connections between Calabi-Yau manifolds and number theory?
I am interested in understanding whether there are any significant connections between Calabi-Yau manifolds and number theory. Calabi-Yau manifolds are central objects in algebraic geometry and string theory due to their rich geometric and topological properties. Meanwhile, number theory explores the arithmetic properties of structures often arising from geometry.
Some specific aspects that come to mind:
Are there known results relating the arithmetic properties of Calabi-Yau manifolds (e.g., their zeta functions or Hodge structures) to modular forms or L-functions?
Do Calabi-Yau manifolds play any role in the Langlands program or broader conjectures in number theory?
Are there notable examples where Calabi-Yau manifolds are used to construct explicit motives or study Galois representations?
I would appreciate references, insights, or examples of connections between these fields. My background includes basic algebraic geometry and number theory, so I’m happy to explore any necessary resources to deepen my understanding.

Hi Abdullah — I think this question would be better suited for math.stackexchange, perhaps as a community wiki ‘big list’ question.

@AlecRhea thanks I will ask it in math.stackexchange

The review "Modularity of Calabi-Yau Varieties" https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0601238 by Klaus Hulek, Remke Kloosterman and Matthias Schütt, while somewhat outdated, will be a useful starting point.

Another useful review is "Update on Modular Non-Rigid Calabi-Yau Threefolds" by Edward Lee https://arxiv.org/pdf/0803.0006.

For arithmetic connections to string theory, look at recent papers of Candelas, de la Ossa and collaborators.

There are also results where generating series of invariants of Calabi-Yau manifolds (such as Pandharipande-Thomas invariants) are shown to be modular. See, e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.07073
